# How to cast a QML object as QQuickWindow from c++ code?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, vtk

I am using `QQmlVTKPlugin`, which allows me to directly access to `VTKRenderWindow` and `VTKRenderItem` with QML. To setup this I need to give to my `QQMLApplicationEngine` a `QQuickWindow` and a `QQuickItem`. If I just do this initialization from the main.cpp everything works correctly but for some reason I need to do that by calling a class constructor inside my QML file with a singleton. I call the following constructor from the QML but when I do `window->show()` my application crashes

```
SceneManage::SceneManage(QObject *topLevel)
{
    window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);   // QQuickWindow window
    window->show();
    QQuickItem *item = topLevel->findChild<QQuickItem *>("3DViewer");
...
```

Does someone have a way to do what I want ?

Comment: Your code is too incoherent and sketchy to understand the issue. If the question is the same as the title so you can use `rootitem.findChild` to find the item by `objectName`. Also using *_cast always assumes that return value can be null so at least it's worth checking out.

Comment: I changed the explanation, I hope that everything is clearer now. I manage to find the correct item but I don't know what happens to my object creating from the QML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : Don't decide to show the window from c++ but only set visible parameter in QML.